# Distribution of conditional expected value

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, moment-generating-functions

Motivated from an application in economics, I would be interested in a simplified solution for $C$, where
\begin{equation*}
C = E\bigg[exp \bigg\{-\frac{1}{2} \frac{(E[\theta|S]-a)^2}{b}\bigg\}\bigg]
\end{equation*}
and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

However, the distribution of $S$ is a normal mixture and thus I could not find any simplified solution for $C$. Can anybody prove me wrong?

The specific setting is as follows: $S$ is a mixture of two normal distributions with equal means and $\eta_1+\eta_2=1$. Specifically,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(S)=\eta_1f_{1\mathcal{N}}(S;\hat{\theta},\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_1}^{2})+\eta_2f_{2\mathcal{N}}(S;\hat{\theta},\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_2}^{2}).                     
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

$\theta$ is $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(\hat{\theta},\sigma_\theta^2)$. The joint distribution of $S$ and $\theta$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f(S,\theta)=\eta_1f_{1\mathcal{N}}(S,\theta;\mu_1,\Sigma_1)+\eta_2f_{2\mathcal{N}}(S,\theta;\mu_2,\Sigma_2)                     ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{\mu_1}=\boldsymbol{\mu_2}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\theta}\\
\hat{\theta}
\end{pmatrix} \quad
\boldsymbol{\Sigma_1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_\theta^2&\sigma_\theta^2\\
\sigma_\theta^2&\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_1}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\boldsymbol{\Sigma_2}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_\theta^2&\sigma_\theta^2\\
\sigma_\theta^2&\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}\quad 
\end{equation*}

One can calculate the values of $E_1[\theta|S]$, $ Var_1[\theta|S]$ based on $f_{1\mathcal{N}}(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $ E_2[\theta|S]$ and $ Var_2[\theta|S]$ based on $f_{2\mathcal{N}}(\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$. It is

\begin{equation*}
E_1[\theta|S]=\hat{\theta}+\frac{\sigma_\theta^2}{\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_1}^{2}}(S-\hat{\theta}) \quad and \quad Var_1[\theta|S]=\sigma_\theta^2-\frac{\sigma_\theta^4}{\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_1}^{2}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
E_2[\theta|S]=\hat{\theta}+\frac{\sigma_\theta^2}{\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_2}^{2}}(S-\hat{\theta}) \quad and \quad Var_2[\theta|S]=\sigma_\theta^2-\frac{\sigma_\theta^4}{\sigma_\theta^2+\sigma_{\epsilon_2}^{2}}
\end{equation*}

and thus it is

\begin{equation}
E[\theta|S]=\dfrac{\eta_1f_{1\mathcal{N}}(S)}{f(S)}E_1[\theta|S]+\dfrac{\eta_2f_{2\mathcal{N}}(S)}{f(S)}E_2[\theta|S].
\end{equation}
I doubt that the distribution of $E[\theta|S]$ is well specified.